# link button implementation

Tags: asp.net

I have a page, main.aspx page. I need to add a link to the main.aspx page. So that when employees clicks on the link, I have to show the employee profile (profile.aspx) page as a pop up. In order to do this can I use link button. I am working on .NET version 1.1. when I use link button I could not find the postbackurl.

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard anchor tag with target="_blank" to open in a new window:

```
<a href="Profile.aspx" target="_blank">View Profile</a>
```

or if you need some server-side processing use the ASP.NET HyperLink control:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypProfile" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="Profile.aspx">View Profile</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: I have to pass data from session object to profile.aspx, based on the session object it opens the page . In above case it is on client side . so I cann't pass the value. is there any other way?

Comment: @user993935 profile.aspx should already have access to the session object itself. Are you trying to show the page only if a value exists in the session?